# How do I remove an ssh private key from ssh-agent/keychain

Tags: password, keychain, ssh

I followed some [aws guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/) to add my private key to ssh-agent, using:

```
ssh-add -K "MyPrivateKey.pem"
```

However, I can't seem to remove the key using :

```
ssh-add -d "MyPrivateKey.pem"
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Bad key file MyPrivateKey.pem: No such file or directory
```

Unless I do  `ssh-add -D` which removes all of the private keys I stored (obviously not favorable option). I also find that macOS ssh key management is tightly bind with Keychain, but I haven't discovered any method to identify the specific ssh key from Keychain Access. I am running on Mojave 10.14.6

tl;dr How do I get  `ssh-add -d` to work on macOS?

Answer (score 6):

After I post the question, I found the answer, the following command will generate the public key using the private key file:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ./MyPrivateKey.pem > ./MyPublicKey.pub
```

then to remove it:

```
ssh-add -d "MyPublicKey.pub"
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334809/linux-how-to-use-ssh-add-to-remove-identities-pem-files-from-the-agent)

Comment: That's weird. man page say: *"-d Deletes the given identities from the agent. The **private** key files for the identities to be deleted should be listed on the command line."* Either way, the easiest way to drop the key in memory is to kill and restart the key-server.